# How to prevent django from loading objects in memory when using `delete()`?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I'm having memory issues because it looks like Django is loading the objects into memory when using `delete()`. Is there any way to prevent Django from doing that?

From the Django docs:

> Django needs to fetch objects into memory to send signals and handle cascades. However, if there are no cascades and no signals, then Django may take a fast-path and delete objects without fetching into memory. For large deletes this can result in significantly reduced memory usage. The amount of executed queries can be reduced, too.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#delete

I don't use signals. I do have foreign keys on the model I'm trying to delete, but I don't see why Django would need to load the objects into memory. It looks like it does, because my memory is rising as the query runs.

Comment: Since you have foreign keys, Django needs to load the objects in order to resolve how the relation should handle the deletion:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: @petkostas I did try to put `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` on my ForeignKey fields, but that didn't help. But it wouldn't be good solution for me anyway, I want to disable loading of the objects in memory for this specific query, I don't want all my queries to ignore the ForeignKey constraints..

Comment: Using raw sql could be a solution.

Comment: @rednaw That is expected behavior, Django needs to resolve the Foreign Key cascade policy, another option would be to send the task to a queue (celery) and rate limit the operations from there.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a function like this to iterate over an huge number of objects without using too much memory:

```
import gc

def queryset_iterator(qs, batchsize = 500, gc_collect = True):
    iterator = qs.values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('pk').distinct().iterator()
    eof = False
    while not eof:
        primary_key_buffer = []
        try:
            while len(primary_key_buffer) < batchsize:
                primary_key_buffer.append(iterator.next())
        except StopIteration:
            eof = True
        for obj in qs.filter(pk__in=primary_key_buffer).order_by('pk').iterator():
            yield obj
        if gc_collect:
            gc.collect()
```

Then you can use the function to iterate over the objects to delete:

```
for obj in queryset_iterator(HugeQueryset.objects.all()):
    obj.delete()
```

For more information you can check [this blog post](https://www.guguweb.com/2020/03/27/optimize-django-memory-usage/).

Comment: That blog post link is offline, sadly.

Comment: Thank you Adam, I fixed the URL of the blog post.

Comment: If you get `'generator' object has no attribute 'next'` in python 3, replace `iterator.next()` by `next(iterator)` and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can import django database connection and use it with sql to delete. I had exact same problem as you do and this helps me a lot. Here's some snippet(I'm using mysql by the way, but you can run any sql statement):

```
from django.db import connection
sql_query = "DELETE FROM usage WHERE date < '%s' ORDER BY date" % date
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
finally:
    c.close()
```

This should execute only the delete operation on that table without affecting any of your model relationships.

Comment: It is likely that the query will fail at the database level, because the objects being deleted have foreign keys pointing to them, and Django put a constraint of type ON DELETE RESTRICT on foreign keys at the DB level.